# Formula help: copy cell, omitting text before and after an item in the cell

Tags: excel-formula

Need to copy "CCCC" while removing the specific text string before CCCC, including "AAAA-BBBB-", and removing everything after "CCCC" (everything after CCCC begins with " assign" and is variable text after that constant)

AAAA, "BBBB" and "CCCC" represent text strings that are variable in characters and number of characters.

[image: image of example]

Example:
Cell to copy: "specific text string hereAAAA-BBBB-CCCC assign and variable text string after"

Result of formula: CCCC

Comment: @scott-craner    Scott, I tried adding wildcards to include the AAAA-BBBB- in the substitute of the specific text string, but it leaves the specific text string in the answer, as well as the CCCC:          =SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(K2,FIND(" assign",K2)-1),"Request to modify technical role*-*-","")

Answer (score 0):

Found some help:

=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J2,"assign",REPT(" ",500)),"-",REPT(" ",500)),1000),500))